# Algebraic Data Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple data type for mathematical expressions. The code I have right now is:

```
data Expr
  = Num Double
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Mul Expr Expr
  | Sin Expr
  | Cos Expr
  | X
  deriving Eq
```

This works as expected but I want to make it simpler with only one line for binary operators (Add and Mul) and one for unary operators (Sin and Cos). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use, e.g.,

```
data BinOp = Add | Mul
data UnaryOp = Sin | Cos

data Expr
  = Num Double
  | Binary BinOp Expr Expr
  | Unary UnaryOp Expr
```

YMMV on whether this is simpler.